# conditional probability with more than one observation

Tags: probability-theory

my professor did a derivation. he prefaced saying that no such notation exists and he wanted to show us why (in the end, he stated that this shows that sequential observation is equivalent to simultaneous observation)

Here is what he wrote:

$\begin{aligned}
P((\cdot |B_1)|B_2) 
&= \frac{P(A \cap B_2 | B_1)}{P(B_2 | B_1)} &= \dots = P(A | B_1 \cap B_2)
\end{aligned}
$

I skip the intermediate skips because I only have a question about the first equality on the left. How are those two things equal? He said it's from the definition, but I'm having trouble seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly he has used A instead of the dot.

Secondly he has used $P((A |B_1)|B_2) = P(A |(B_1|B_2))$.

This is because if you want the probability of the triple events $B_2$ then $B_1$ then $A$, it doesn't matter whether you do it as  ($B_2$ then $B_1$) then $A$, or as $B_2$ then ($B_1$ then $A$).